# Div positioning and scaling on variable table using knockout

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I want to make an overlay(div) for a table with a variable number of rows. The entire table has to be covered so I want:

- The position to be the same.
- The height to be the same.
- the width to be the same.

My code looks similar to this, I removed part of the code for this example.

```
// the overlay
<div data-bind="style: {position: 'absolute', zIndex: '999999'}"></div>

// the table
<table data-bind="foreach: fields">
   <tbody class="formGroup">
      <tr>
        <th>
            <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            // the field comes here
            <!-- ko template:--><!-- /ko -->
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So I'm wondering what the best way is to make the div place directly above the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to add a wrapper with `position: relative`. This way, the overlay will be positioned relative to this wrapper.

```
<div class="overlay-wrapper">
    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <p>Some dynamic height</p>
    <p>Some dynamic height</p>
    <p>Some dynamic height</p>
    <p>Some dynamic height</p>
    <p>Some dynamic height</p>
    <p>Some dynamic height</p>
    <p>Some dynamic height</p>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.overlay-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-wrapper .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o13qaqc1/